# epoch time to human readable from SQL output. HTML

Tags: javascript, html, sql, sql-server

I have an query which gets date from database but the problem is that we are using epoch/unix time. I currently working on an easy website which will be outputting creating date (dateadd in sql).

Query:

```
select takeover from realest where id=objid as Dato where ...
```

I have something like this in HTML:

```
<tr class="tr{row}" valign="center">
    <td class="td" align="left" nowrap>{'Dato(DO.dato).ToString("%d.%m.%Y");'}</td>
```

But it doesnt work. How can i fix that?

Comment: is this a question about javascript, html or sql ?

Comment: java script. It's last line